# ruby grape entity - inheritance, the son does not contain the parent's fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, entity, grape-entity

I would expect to get json with both the name and note fields. But I only get the note field. What am I doing wrong?

```
class OrderPage
  module Entities
    class AsSeller < OrderPage::Entities::Order
      expose :note

      def note
        object.note
      end
    end
  end
end

class OrderPage
  module Entities
    class Order < Grape::Entity
       expose :name
    end
  end
end

 json = OrderPage::Entities::AsSeller.represent(order).as_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your case you should receive an error on your third row

```
uninitialized constant OrderPage::Entities::Order
```

But changing the order, making `class Order` defined higher than `class AsSeller` — all looks good, the JSON is rendered with both fields.

If that doesn't help you can also try updating gem versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a step back and remember that *an entity is supposed to represent an object*, because it doesn't really seem like that's what you're doing here. So you should have *one* entity representing your codebase's concept of an Order object (AsSeller sounds like a visibility restriction, not an object), and use `with_options` to restrict what is or is not exposed.

```rb
module Entities
  class Order < Grape::Entity
    expose :name

    with_options(if: { visibility: :seller }) do
      expose :note
    end
  end
end

order = { name: 'Relax', note: "Don't do it" }

# Standard order representation
Entities::Order.represent(order).serializable_hash
=> {:name=>"Relax"}

# Order represented with visibility: :seller
Entities::Order.represent(order, visibility: :seller).serializable_hash
=> {:name=>"Relax", :note=>"Don't do it"}
```

Alternatively, if it's just a matter of conditionally exposing an attribute that only exists on certain descendants of the order model, you should be able to do something like this:

```rb
expose :note, if: ->(order, _) { order.respond_to?(:note) }
```

If you really need to include a subset of attributes defined elsewhere, you could write a Concern and *include* it in another entity, but from the context available to me in your question and the naming you've used, it doesn't seem like that's a good solution here.